# /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, path, rbenv

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and I have installed ruby with rbenv months ago. Everything was working fine but I believed I messed with $PATH doing other stuff and now it says `/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory` every time I try to use a command related to ruby.

```
rbenv versions
2.2.3

echo $PATH
/home/rafael/.rbenv/shims:/home/rafael/.rbenv/bin:/home/rafael/.rbenv/shims:/home/rafael/.rbenv/bin:/home/rafael/.rbenv/shims:/home/rafael/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/home/rafael/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/rafael/.rbenv/shims:/home/rafael/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/rafael/.rvm/bin:/home/rafael/.rvm/bin
```

It is possible to find ruby 2.2.3 inside rbenv versions but it is like it is not installed. I am thinking of deleting everything and reinstall ruby. But I want to believe that there is a simpler solution that I am not seeing. Help, please.

Comment: Seems like rbenv is not installed properly on your machine. Could you paste your .bash_profile/ .bashrc if you are on Bash or .zshrc if you use Zsh ?

Comment: @alotofnoodles  .bash_profile  <br/> `[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export PATH="/home/rafael/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/home/rafael/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: @alotofnoodles .bashrc  `# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
...
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
`

Answer (score 0):

It's one of 2 things

1. The path that crontab uses doesn't have your Ruby in it. This is usually because the "safe" path that cron uses doesn't include `/usr/local/bin`
2. Cron isn't finding the rbenv paths on the server.

You can set the path explicitly in your crontab and see if that fixes it in either case.